# split x-axis value into multiple lines in p:barchart

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am trying to wrap overlapped text on x-axis of p:barchart
for this i used css like word-wrap and white-space but still it is not working
Kindly help me to solve it

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using `xaxisAngle` tag of PrimeFaces.